# How can I get different colours of ocean?

Tags: planets, chemistry, ocean, unusual-color

We think of oceans and large lakes as being blue.

How can I get other colours in a way that is reasonably compatible with what we know from terrestial bio-geo-chemistry?

Comment: What are you looking for here, an itemized list?  That's either TB (there's a book's worth of chemical compounds that are liquid at room temperature and not blue), or POB, or quite possibly both.  Please narrow it down for us.

Comment: Also, possibly relevent Chemistry.SE question that was closed as TB: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/what-elements-and-or-substances-without-water-are-liquid-at-room-temperature  Interestingly, the answer mentions Francium as an element that is almost liquid at room temperature.   I do not want to know how someone determined the melting point of Francium.

Comment: @Gryphon I'm just looking for one example or more, provided the example hasn't been said by another answerer.

Comment: what criteria make one answer better than another?  Without some sort of criteria for choosing answers, the question is POB.

Comment: @Gryphon Fair enough. I'll give a few colours in the question body, and then the answerer can present an example for each.

Comment: Are you simply asking what the reflected wavelengths are for [this list of liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalassogen)?  What research have you done yourself?

Comment: "And now have I put in here, as thou seest, with ship and crew, while sailing over the *wine-dark sea* to men of strange speech, on my way to Temese for copper; and I bear with me shining iron." (Homer, [*The Odyssey*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0136%3Abook%3D1%3Acard%3D178), 1:180, English trans. by A.T. Murray, 1919)

Comment: Iron pentacarbonyl can be yellow or orange. See Baxter's Manifold:Space.

Comment: I have voted to re-open it as, while broad, it has solicited interesting answers.

Comment: I don't see why this is closed? This is essentially asking for a list of colors that can be made for bodies of water that harbor life and that occur naturally.

Answer (score 7):

**Red Algae**

The easiest way to get a non-green/blue ocean is perhaps to use a life form. Just make sure your ocean has the ideal nutrients for them.

[image]

**Salt Lake in Turkey Turns Red Because of Algae Bloom**

https://abcnews.go.com/International/salt-lake-turkey-turns-red-algae-bloom/story?id=32590572

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ammonia has a tendency to dissolve alkaline metals. [This answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/what-would-an-ammonia-based-world-look-like) claims this would make the oceans very blue, [this page](https://planetstar.fandom.com/wiki/Ammonia_planet) suggests brown. The argument for blue is that [solvated electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvated_electron) make solutions deep blue; when the concentration is high ($[H]>3$M) the colour goes copper, which might be the source for the brown. Now, that is a pretty concentrated solution, so I would expect blue unless there were other substances adding colour.

Liquid nitrogen, helium and hydrogen are pretty colourless, but [liquid oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen) is sky-blue (and under pressure and low temperature forms a lot of colourful crystal phases). Ozone is darker blue. Hydrogen perioxide is apparently a watery transparent blue. Of course, a planet with liquid oxidant oceans may have some habitability issues. I suspect that the same dispersion effects that make water blue will make liquid nitrogen, helium and hydrogen oceans look blueish.

Hydrocarbon have plenty of opportunities to acquire colour. Liquid methane is again colorless, and [might look very clear on worlds like Titan](http://www.saers.com/recorder/craig/titan/LiquidMethaneOnTitan.html) where atmospheric methane has already filtered out the wavelengths that tend to be absorbed. However, the atmospheric haze consisting of photochemical smog is clearly yellowish and likely soluble in the methane. I would expect most hydrocarbon ocean planets to have oceans coloured by more complex [tholin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tholin) molecules, that would tend towards the red-yellow side. In extreme cases, maybe black.

Sulphuric acid is again colorless, but does tend to turn yellowish when contaminated with iron ions. And again organic matter and other substances can make it yellow, red, or black.

Answer (score 3):

Water isn't blue.  Or not very.  Water appears blue-ish because most of the light you are seeing is reflected sky. It's not the same blue, because some of it is absorbed instead, so you are in effect getting dimmed skylight, or light blue mixed with black.

[[image: Showing variable colour by semi-specular reflection[1]]
*Here the surface is calm enough that there is only small amounts of surface scattering.*

[image: View at a sharper angle]
*At the top of the picture you see a mottle of blue and dark bands.  The blue bands are the back side of the wave. Reverse the light path from your eye, the water is at a shallower angle, so reflection dominates.  The front side of the wave is show more light from the interior of the water.*

*Look at the reflection of the bow of the canoe. This area has a poor view of skylight, so the colour here is a mix of some bottom algae, and red light reflected from the canoe.*

[image: Smoky day]

*On a smoky overcast day, the water looks like hammered metal.*

Water can be coloured by what's in it.  Suspended clay gives it a brown colour.  Dissolved tannic acid (peat bogs) along with micron sized peat particles make it the colour of strong tea in your cup, black if more than a foot deep.

[image: Shallow windy water]
*Stormy shallow water.  In the shallow water at the end of this lake wave action has lifted some of the bottom sediment int suspension, giving the water a brownish cast.*

[image: Rapid]

*Smooth water in foreground and background shows bluish tinge of sky.  White water is light scattered off of entrained air.  The light brown is organics from the peat bogs that is the source for the water.

With algae in it water is green.  There can be a substantial difference in green depending on which algae.  Some algae are red -- hence red tide.

Runoff water from a glacier is often a milky gray initially.  As it gets far enough and slow enough for larger rock flour particles to settle, it takes on a blue cast.  The particles that remain are are close in size to the wave length of blue light, so it's scattered more.

[image: Abraham Lake]
*Abraham Lake is coloured by rock flour.  The water here is only about 30 miles from it's source on the Columbia Ice Fields in Jasper Park.

[image: Crater Lake on cloudy day]

*Several comments have mentioned Crater Lake.  On a  day of broken overcast it doesn't appear particularly blue.  I suspect much of it's reputation is due to being at high elevation, so the sky also is an extraordinary blue.*

So now you have several mechanisms to colour water:

- Suspended solids
- Dissolved solids
- Micro-organisms.
- Sky reflections.

There is no reason for any of these to not work with other liquids.

Comment: `Water appears blue-ish because most of the light you are seeing is reflected sky`  That is a fantastic statement - which would be even more fantastic if you could supply a link to a reasonably scholarly reference to substantiate it. (I am in no way saying you're wrong, I'm just hoping for the improvement).

Comment: "Water appears blue-ish because most of the light you are seeing is reflected sky" is a myth.
https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-the-ocean-appear/

Comment: Water is blue because [it preferentially absorbs longer wavelengths of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Water_absorption_coefficient_large.gif).  Go look at [Crater Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crater_Lake) sometime.  The water there is incredibly clear, incredibly pure, and incredibly blue, even on cloudy days.

Comment: @JBH I have also heard the statement about the reflected sky somewhere, and found it to be true afterwards. The "color" of any water surface is dominated by what that water surface reflects, followed by what chemicals/particles are found at/directly under the surface. In the absense of these things, water is just almost fully transparent. Yet, because it still does absorb some tiny amounts of light like any other material, deep bodies of pure water would look just black without the sky reflecting off their surfaces.

Comment: @cmaster, see my note above.  Crater Lake is a deep body of pure water, and it looks intensely blue under virtually all conditions.

Comment: @Mark I've never been to Crater Lake. However, from the images in the wikipedia, it always looks like a darkened, slightly blue-shifted version of the sky above. And I really doubt it would look blue under a bloody red sunset...

Comment: @cmaster, it's still pretty blue [even when you're looking through a mile of smoke](https://imgur.com/fuflPyv), though you're right about the sunset -- [it turns a sort of muddy orange](https://imgur.com/qIJwUsP).

Comment: @cmaster No, sorry, [water is blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water#Color_and_appearance).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Read the entire text. Right at the beginning: "The apparent color of natural bodies of water (and swimming pools) is often determined more by dissolved and suspended solids, or by reflection of the sky, than by water itself." And then, later on, we see how much water is necessary to get to the point where you can actually appreciate its own color: "Through a thickness of 10 meters (33 ft) or more, however, the intrinsic color of water (or ice) is visibly turquoise (greenish blue)" The point is, that this 10m color is largely irrelevant to the appearance of the surface.

Comment: @JBH Mostly personal experience.  I have spent months of my life canoeing lakes and rivers of various depths and sizes in various weather and lighting.